# Do not flood with post-receive emails during GIT repo creation

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I am trying to stop the flood of emails for the first time of GIT repo creation. For example, let us say I am moving from SVN to GIT and I do not want to get the flood of emails for the commits already created in SVN.

I would also like to know the use cases when I can stop flooding of emails for already existing commits.

I am planning to do this from post-receive hook and I am using gitolite.

Comment: Can you post the hook you're using that's generating the flood of emails?

Comment: In post-receive hook we control the mails using hooks.sendmail. I do not want to update that parameter on the gitolite side for each and every small repo creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (<>) 
{
            chomp;
                next unless ($old_rev, $new_rev ,$ref_name) =
                    m/ ^ ([0-9a-f]+) \s+    # old SHA-1
                         ([0-9a-f]+) \s+    # new SHA-1
                         (.*?) # ref_name
                     \s* $ /x;

            my $send_email = _git_cmd_exec("git config hooks.sendmailalert");

            if ($send_email) {
                generate_and_send_mail();
            }
        }
```